Quarkus Log Severity Always Shows as INFO in Log Explorer
I am using Quarkus 3.15.1 along with java.util.logging (JUL) for logging in my service application on GKE. However, I've encountered an issue where all the logs in GCP Log Explorer show the severity as INFO, even when the log level in my java.util.logging configuration is set to WARNING or SEVERE.
This is the maven project dependencies
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkiverse.googlecloudservices</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I have customized my own Logger class based on java.util.logging (JUL), which uses three levels: INFO, WARNING, and SEVERE.

By default, the logger is set to the INFO level.
For expected error situations, I use the WARNING level.
For unexpected error situations, I use the SEVERE level.

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public final class Logger {

    private static final Map<String, Logger> INSTANCES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private java.util.logging.Logger logger;

    public Logger(java.util.logging.Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private Logger(String clazzName) {
        setLogger(java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clazzName));
    }

    public java.util.logging.Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

    private void setLogger(java.util.logging.Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public static Logger getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        return INSTANCES.computeIfAbsent(clazz.getName(), Logger::new);
    }

    public void info(String msg) {
        info(() -> msg);
    }

    public void info(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        getLogger().info(supplier);
    }

    public void warning(String msg) {
        warning(() -> msg);
    }

    public void warning(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        getLogger().warning(supplier);
    }

    public void log(Level level, String msg) {
        log(level, () -> msg);
    }

    public void log(Level level, Supplier<String> supplier) {
        getLogger().log(level, supplier);
    }

    public void log(Level level, Throwable thrown, String msg) {
        log(level, thrown, () -> msg);
    }

    public void log(Level level, Throwable thrown, Supplier<String> supplier) {
        getLogger().log(level, thrown, supplier);
    }
}

My expectation is that, in GCP Log Explorer, the log severity should accurately reflect the level set by the java.util.logging settings (e.g., WARNING, SEVERE).
But currently the log severity in GCP Log Explorer always shows as INFO, regardless of the log level I set.
insertId,"labels.""compute.googleapis.com/resource_name""","labels.""k8s-pod/app""","labels.""k8s-pod/pod-template-hash""",logName,receiveLocation,receiveTimestamp,resource.labels.cluster_name,resource.labels.container_name,resource.labels.location,resource.labels.namespace_name,resource.labels.pod_name,resource.labels.project_id,resource.type,severity,textPayload,timestamp
7k6b2gi2asl9n914,gke-nonprod-default-large-pool-ca2b5391-xe5b,storage,77695fb78c,projects/nonprod/logs/stdout,,2024-12-12T02:13:13.114608567Z,nonprod,storage,europe-west6-a,dev,storage-77695fb78c-gwlng,nonprod,k8s_container,INFO,"2024-12-12 03:13:10,424 INFO  [my.sto.con.RestClientFilter] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) [DELETE] - http://cache:8080/cache/api/public/vault_v1_transit_keys_exists status-code=200 time-consuming=9",2024-12-12T02:13:10.425241392Z
sqjje3t6gy5ev4wr,gke-nonprod-default-large-pool-ca2b5391-xe5b,storage,77695fb78c,projects/nonprod/logs/stdout,,2024-12-12T02:13:13.114608567Z,nonprod,storage,europe-west6-a,dev,storage-77695fb78c-gwlng,nonprod,k8s_container,INFO,"2024-12-12 03:13:10,414 **WARNING** [my.sto.con.RestClientFilter] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) [POST] - http://vault:8200/v1/transit/decrypt/public status-code=403 time-consuming=10",2024-12-12T02:13:10.414728121Z
87gz8y7nfkjnzsi6,gke-nonprod-default-large-pool-ca2b5391-xe5b,storage,77695fb78c,projects/nonprod/logs/stdout,,2024-12-12T02:13:13.114608567Z,nonprod,storage,europe-west6-a,dev,storage-77695fb78c-gwlng,nonprod,k8s_container,INFO,"2024-12-12 03:13:10,403 INFO  [my.sto.con.RestClientFilter] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) [GET] - http://cache:8080/cache/api/public/vault_v1_auth_jwt_login status-code=200 time-consuming=7",2024-12-12T02:13:10.404261889Z

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can offer guidance on how to ensure that the correct log level appears in GCP Log Explorer?

By default, all the output made on the STDOUT is gather by Google Cloud and logged as info. If you want to customize the log level, you have to write directly in Cloud Logging. There is libraries and example to achieve it easily: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#example
